# asp core изменить путь в Action

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, маршрутизация

Есть action Details(int?id ...) и к нему можно обратится по следующим путям:

**Home/Details/id

page/id

page/id/slug**

И он вернет страницу с теми же путями. пример:

Запрос: **page/5**  Ответ: **page/5**

Мне нужно в этом action переопределить путь, что бы он возвращал всегда последний, Пример:

Запрос: **page/5**  Ответ: **page/5/slug**

action знает о slug(достает из бд по id),

Это возможно сделать? Как?

---

### UPDATE

Перепробовал много вариантов но **Redirect** не происходит. Возвращает ошибку **500**

```
 public async Task<IActionResult> Details(int? id)
    {           

        if (TempData["ReturnData"] != null)//сюда даже не заходит 
        {
            return View(TempData["ReturnData"]);
        }



        var returnData = new{...};



        if (RouteData.Values["slug"] == null && ! string.IsNullOrEmpty(returnData.slug))
        {
            TempData["ReturnData"] = returnData;
            var redirect = $"/page/{returnData.id}/{returnData.slug}";//тут перепробовал 100500 вариантов...
            return Redirect(redirect); // пробовал также RedirectToRoute и RedirectToAction             
        }

        return View(returnData);
    }
```

...

```
routes.MapRoute(
        "Slug", 
         "page/{id}/{slug?}", 
          new { controller = "Home", action = "Details" } 
        );
```

Answer (score 1):

```
return Redirect("page/id/slug");
```

Comment: допустим. Как я понял нужно проверить привальный ли пришел путь, если нет, то вернуть Redirect? Как можно проверить что путь содержит slug?

Comment: @user282446 `RouteData.Values["slug"] != null`

Comment: 2 часа ковырял программу, но ничего не получилось. Обновил вопрос